# Python Combine multiple List in a function

Tags: python, list

Hi I am stuck at combining all list as a final list. The code is to find the possible combination of subset string, given a main string.

The code is able to find all the possible combination however I dont know how to combine the results

```
#for 'abcd', given ['a','b','c','bc','d']

#the out put shall be
#[['a','b','c','d'],['a','bc','d']]
```

```
def canConstruct(target_string,words,memo=None,):

  if memo == None: memo = dict()
  
  if target_string in memo:
    return memo[target_string]
 
  if target_string == "": return []

  for word in words:
    if target_string.startswith(word):
      remainder_string = target_string[len(word):]
      bank =  canConstruct(remainder_string,words,memo)
      bank = [word] + bank
      print(bank)
  return bank

print(canConstruct('abcd',['a','bc','b','c','d']))
```

Comment: It's not entirely obvious how that input shall yield that output. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Hi input of target_string = "abcd" and words =[a,b, bc, c, d] shall yield [a, b, c, d] and [a, bc, d]

Comment: But… [why?](https://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/022/978/yNlQWRM.jpg)

Comment: Cause a, b, c, d can be used to form abcd so as a, bc, d

Comment: Yeah, fine… if you want help with your algorithm, you should be able to explain what the algorithm is supposed to do. Like… logically. Not just *input → ??? → output*, but explain the "???" in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the results in a list:

```
# ...
if target_string == "":
    return [[]]  # result is list of lists!
result = []
for word in words:
    if target_string.startswith(word):
        remainder_string = target_string[len(word):]
        for cc in canConstruct(remainder_string, words, memo):
            result.append([word] + cc)
memo[target_string] = result
return result
```

Comment: Hi @schwobaseggl Can you please explain on the result.append. I was thinking that for each result appended. It will pass to the appended result to the next loop: eg For target_string = 'abc' for given set ['a','bc']. When there is no string left, it will return [[]], then result.append(['bc']+[]) = [['bc']]. Then when when collecting the next word 'a'. Shouldnt the result.append gives [['bc'], ['a','bc']]? where the result[0] is from the previous loop. Sorry if describe is not good

Comment: The scenario you describe, `cc` is `['bc']` as we loop over `[['bc']]`. So we append `['a']+['bc']` to the still empty `result` list, producing finel result `[['a', ''bc]]`. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Hi @schwobaseggl. Thanks! Can you further explain why the `result` is `empty` and not `[['bc']]` from the previous loop? As previously we perform `result.append`?

Comment: At every function call we start out with an empty result list: `result = []`. The result lists from earlier (recursive) calls exist only in that we use their elements (those are the `cc`) to construct the new result list in the current call.